# How do I log to a table in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server, logging, log4net

I'm writing into a log file, but I want to log into a table named "Log" in my database.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: If you have an exact question please edit your question, if someone understands better then I do what this person is asking, please edit the question.

Answer (score 3):

log4net has an [AdoNetAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.html), and a [sample configuration right here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html).

Comment: The huge advantage of using log4net too, is that you can switch between logging to your SQL server, and any other method you like (files, event log...whatever) by simply altering your config file.

Answer (score 2):

Check out logging.apache.org for the log4X that fits the language you are using.  I know they have log4j (Java) and log4net (C#/.Net).  They also have examples on how to configure the logging framework to log to a database table instead of a file.